# window:scroll event doesn't trigger with @HostListener

Tags: angular, events, dom-events

I have this `@HostListener` in my component that is supposed to listened on the scroll event on the window object :

```
 export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
  } }
```

Nothing happens. If I change it to a click event, it detects the event on the whole window, as expected :

```
    export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostListener('window:click', ['$event'])
  onScroll(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
  } }
```

I tried to set a scroll event directly on the main div, or with an eventListener on the window, nothing works.

Any idea why ?

Comment: Try this `Observable.fromEvent(window, "scroll").subscribe(e => {
               console.log(e.target);
            });`, Is it working for you?

Comment: `window:scroll`, `document:scroll` or even `scroll` on an element do not trigger if there is no scrolling that occur on the page/element. I think what you are trying to listen to is the event that comes from using the mouse wheel, isn't it? See [related stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmzpnz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Are you using any third-party components?

Comment: @Askirkela You're probably right, I did not think about that. Actually the element I'm scrolling on is a map, using the Mapbox API, so there is no actual page scroll. The mouse scroll command triggers the zoom in/out in the map.

Comment: @DevangPatel yes, I think the problem comes from the fact that I'm displaying a map from the Mapbox API and the scroll event is already used by it (but I don't know how). There is then no actual scrolling on the page. What I should try to do is to get the mouse wheel event itself, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem by getting the `mousewheel` event instead of the `scroll` event.
As there was no actual scrolling in the page the scroll event was never triggered.

Comment: this is working only using mousewheel, it isn't working if you scroll using the scrollbar. do you know any solution for this?